# Rails Namespace - Calling Model From Second Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces

I'm currently using Devise for user authentication and I would like to implement a backend admin to control the creation of users in the admin panel.

I have generated an admin controller and I've added a namespace to my routes.

```
-> routes.rb

namespace :admin do
  resources :users
end
```

When I rake routes I get the following

```
         admin_users GET    /admin/users(.:format)            admin/users#index
                     POST   /admin/users(.:format)            admin/users#create
      new_admin_user GET    /admin/users/new(.:format)        admin/users#new
     edit_admin_user GET    /admin/users/:id/edit(.:format)   admin/users#edit
          admin_user GET    /admin/users/:id(.:format)        admin/users#show
                     PUT    /admin/users/:id(.:format)        admin/users#update
                     DELETE /admin/users/:id(.:format)        admin/users#destroy
```

Which is what we want right? Now my question is, what is the naming convention for the functions in the admin controller?

How do I name my functions so they correspond to the following paths? I place the functions in the user controller or the admin?

I'm getting a routing error

```
uninitialized constant Admin
```

I don't think I've gotten the hang of routing just yet. Any additional resources would also be much appreciated.

I've been looking at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing with not much success though. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a typical setup for namespaced controllers (pay careful attention to the inheritance):

```
# app/controllers/admin/base_controller.rb:
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
end

# app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb:
class Admin::UsersController < Admin::BaseController
  # here, you can define all of the methods shown by 'rake routes':
  def index
    # ...
  end

  def show
    # ...
  end

  # etc...
end
```

The `Admin::BaseController` provides a nice top-level class for the admin namespace, similar to how the `ApplicationController` relates to the rest of your controllers. You can throw a `before_filter` in here to authorize admin users only, which will be called before any method from classes that inherit from the base controller.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was testing your code and I got carried away and forgot to thank you hehe.

Comment: I have another question! Now when I go to the url /admin/users/new it's pointing the new function inside the user controller. I tried restarting the server to no avail. Hmm. Any thoughts?